# Exceptions in an asynchronous loop

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have something like this:

```
void GenerateReports() {
    foreach (var employee in employees) {
        GenerateReport(employee);
    }
}
```

GenerateReport takes long time, and I don't want to block my UI thread, so I run this method in a separate thread.

However, GenerateReport occasionaly throws an exception. I want to handle each exception in my UI thread, and continue with the next employee. How do I do this while generating reports asynchronously? If I put GenerateReport in another thread, the foreach loop will be very fast and all reports are created at the same time:

```
void GenerateReports() {
    foreach (var employee in employees) {
        GenerateReportAsync(employee, OnDoneCallback); // returns immediately
    }
}
```

I still want to create one report at a time, but in a seperate thread, and handling an exception for each employee. How can I best implement this?

Comment: Are you in .NET 4.0 and can use the TPL?  TPL makes it easy to examine exceptions from Tasks.

Comment: I am currently using .NET 3.5 but I consider upgrading my application to .NET 4.0 if that makes things easier.

Comment: okay, would you prefer a 3.5 answer though?  I personally find the 4.0 TPL makes handling async processes a lot easier, but if there's compelling reasons for you to want to stay with 3.5 that's fine too.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer a 3.5 answer.

Comment: is GenerateReport in another class? You can basically tweak Keith's answer a bit to achieve that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a BackGround Worker for threading you can use its BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). To send Data Back to your UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

I would put a try-catch around the parts of your method that will throw errors, and if you want them to be handed back to the UI thread, create a method you can pass as a callback:

```
void OnErrorCallback(Exception ex)
{
   if(InvokeRequired)
   {
      //bring method execution up to the UI thread
      this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(()=>OnErrorCallback(ex)));
      return;
   }

   //handle the exception, with access to UI components.
}

void GenerateReports() {
    foreach (var employee in employees) {
        GenerateReportAsync(employee, OnDoneCallback); // returns immediately
    }
}

void GenerateReportAsync(Employee employee, AsyncCallback OnDoneCallback)
{
    //Delegate.BeginInvoke takes all parameters of the delegate, plus 
    //something to call when done, PLUS a state object that can be 
    //used to monitor work in progress (null is fine too).
    GenerateReport.BeginInvoke(employee, OnErrorCallback, OnDoneCallback, null);
}

void GenerateReport(Employee employee, Action<Exception> errorCallback)
{
    try
    {
        //do your dirty work
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //execute the delegate, which will re-execute itself on the UI 
        //thread if necessary. You're basically rethrowing the exception 
        //"sideways" to the UI thread, rather than up the call stack.
        errorCallback(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background worker class..Something like this.

```
void GenerateReports()
{
var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker.DoWork += ((s, e) =>
    {
        // time consuming function
        foreach (var employee in employees)
            GenerateReport(employee);
    }); 

backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += ((s, e) =>
    {
        //do something
    });

backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
} 

delegate void Update(Employee employee);
static void GenerateReport(Employee employee)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Update updaterDelegate = new Update(GenerateReport);
        this.Invoke(updaterDelegate, new object[] { employee });
    }
    else
        GenerateReport(employee)
}
```